# Displaying Recent Authors in Expression Engine

Tags: expressionengine, author

I'm trying to put together the code to display 3 most recent authors in my blog using Expression Engine.

This is the piece of code I am starting with:

```
<dl class="authors">
    {exp:channel:entries channel="{embed:my_channel}" limit="3" dynamic="no" site="{embed:my_site}"}
        <dt><span class="photo"><img src="{avatar_url}" width="{avatar_image_width}" height="{avatar_image_height}" alt="{author}'s Photo"></span></dt>
        <dd>{author}</dd>
    {/exp:channel:entries} 
</dl>
```

Now, the thing I am not quite sure how to code is to get the last 3 authors who posted entries.  You see, the last 3 entries might have been posted by the same author, in which case we'd have to go through more entries to get the other 2 most recent authors.  This is where I am stuck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This can be created simply with the query module.  I've included how to combine the query to give you custom fields for the author, if you have set those up as well:

NOTE: I have not tested the specific details of this code (with your embed codes, etc) - although I was able to test the query.

If you don't have (or want) custom member field data, you can remove those lines from the query.

```
<dl class="authors">
{exp:query sql="
SELECT DISTINCT
    exp_members.username,
    exp_members.member_id,
    exp_members.email,
    exp_members.screen_name as author,
    exp_members.avatar_filename,
    exp_members.avatar_width,
    exp_members.avatar_height,
    exp_member_data.m_field_id_1 as my_custom_member_field
FROM
    exp_channel_titles,
    exp_members,
    exp_member_data
WHERE
    exp_members.member_id = exp_channel_titles.author_id
    AND
    exp_channel_titles.channel_id = '{embed:my_channel}'
    AND
    exp_members.member_id = exp_member_data.member_id
    AND
    exp_channel_titles.site_id = '{embed:my_site}'
ORDER BY
    exp_channel_titles.entry_id DESC" limit='3'}
    <dt><span class="photo"><img src="{avatar_url}" width="{avatar_width}" height="{avatar_height}" alt="{author}'s Photo"></span></dt>
    <dd>{author}</dd>
{/exp:query}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, user2125185, but you put me on the right track.  However, I am still not getting exactly what I am after.

I had to explicitly specify the channel ID (of 1) to select the correct channel, as opposed to the channel name as you have in your example.

The problem I am getting now is that the sorting order is incorrect.  So, I am wondering if it is selecting the right members.  To clarify, I want to select the 3 most recent members who posted in a specific channel (ID 1 for my blog channel) and listed from the most recent post's member to the least recent post's member.